# Code behind button only posting back, not calling javascript function

Tags: asp.net

I am building a page from the code behind.  I add a button and set its attributes like this:

```
var Button1 = new Button();
Button1.Text = "Purge Course Comments";
Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javascript: Purge();");
pageButtons.Controls.Add(Button1);
```

The button is being added to a div called "pageButtons".  When I test the program, the button appears on the screen normally, but when I click it, nothing happens other than the browser posting back.

This page must be built from the code behind, so I can't add the button directly to the page, like this (which would work):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Close Window" OnClientClick="Purge;"/>
```

Basically, I need to be able to call the function from the code behind, but I'm not having much luck.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've looked at the similar questions on Stackoverflow, but I can't find a single one that has an answer that works for me in this situation.

EDIT: For clarity, here's the purge function that I've defined on the page:

```
function PurgeCourse() {
        strCourseId = getQueryString("Id");
        if (strCourseId == "") {
            strCourseId = getQueryString("CourseId");
        }
        window.open("Purge.aspx?id=" + strCourseId);
        parent.window.close();
    }
```

If I just add the button manually to the page, as in the example above, it works.  However, I can't seem to call it from the code behind.

EDIT: I tried a suggestion from below and now my code looks like this:

```
var Button1 = new Button();
Button1.Text = "Purge Course Comments";
Button1.OnClientClick = "javascript: Purge();";
pageButtons.Controls.Add(Button1);
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work either.  I will reiterate, though, that the function does work if I manually add the button to the page and set the OnClientClick attribute to call Purge().  It just seems that I can't get to the function from the code behind, which is frustrating because I can't see why.  This is a small test page with only a function and a div and the code behind.  I can't see where the problem is.

EDIT: I just tried another thing, just to see if it would work.  I did the following:

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "javascript: parent.window.close();";
```

And this worked, so the button can at least use inline javascript code.  It's just not "seeing" my function that's on the page from the code behind.

Comment: As you're dynamically building the page, I assume you've defined the client-side `Purge` function somewhere else and have included it in the page? Also, I'm fairly sure you should add it like `Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Purge();");`

Comment: why is there "javascript: " in the code behind? You are not using it in the version that you claim works. I would leave it out.

Comment: Yes, I have the Purge() function defined in the code behind.  I'll post it above for clarity.

Comment: Don't add `OnClientClick` as an attribute to the output. It is a property of the Button class, so simply do `Button1.OnClientClick = "javascript: Purge();";`

Comment: Also, I forgot and left the javaScript: in the code.  It was one of the methods I have tried that I found via Stackoverflow.

Comment: @metadings I'll give that a try and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: @metadings Unfortunately, I'm getting the same result: on button click, the page just posts back.  I do appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add `OnClientClick` as an attribute to the output. This is a property of the Button class, on the server side, so simply do

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "javascript: PurgeCourse();";

<asp:Button runat="server" onclientclick="javascript: PurgeCourse();" />
```

On the client side, this is rendered into the `onclick` attribute.

```
<button onclick="javascript: PurgeCourse();" />
```

Usually to stop processing of events, this is also known as `event.preventDefault()` (Microsoft didn't like/get this until recently), or `return false`. So your function either always returns false,

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "javascript: PurgeCourse(); return false;";
```

Or you return the value of your function, so that can decide if the submission is terminated or continued:

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "javascript: return PurgeCourse();";

<script type="text/javascript">
function PurgeCourse () {
   return false; // or return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same result: on button click, the page just posts back. I do appreciate the help though! It just seems that, somehow, my code behind can't "see" this function.

Comment: well you defined a `function PurgeCourse()` so you have to call it exactly by name. most likely you got an "Error: Purge is undefined" in your javascript console!

Comment: Also, since the page is being built directly from the code behind, I cannot add and <ASP:Button> to the page directly.  For all intents, the page only has a div tag for me to add the button to.

Comment: You're right!  OMG, I was calling the function with the wrong name!  I never even spotted that.  Thank you so much!  Apparently, that was the problem all along.  The codebehind was calling Purge() when it should've been calling PurgeCourse()!  Thanks, Metadings!

Comment: Always have one eye into your console when writing javaScript, it saves you a lot of time!

Comment: That's a good practice that I haven't been doing.  It'll be first on my list of things to check now when things aren't going like I think they should.  Thanks again for your help and patience!